# How to test form using a ng5-slider with cypress?

Tags: angular, cypress

Has anyone an idea how to test a ng5-slider (e.g. changing the value) with cypress. I tried the suggestions from the documentation(like using trigger) but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with `type('{rightarrow} {rightarrow}')` to move the slider towards right and test for the new value obtained. The below sample test that I have tried in `ng5-slider` sample site and it works fine. Identify the slider and move with `type()` method. The default slider value is `100` and after moving the slider the changed value is `103'

```
describe('Try an Ng Slider test ', function () {
  it('Check the slider and test the new slider value', function () {
    cy.visit('https://angular-slider.github.io/ng5-slider/')
    cy.get('a:contains("Go to demo")').parents('.mt-4').find('a').contains("Go to demo").click()
    cy.wait(1000)
    cy.get('#simple-slider').find('ng5-slider').find('span[aria-valuetext="100"]').type('{rightarrow}{rightarrow}{rightarrow}')
    cy.get('#simple-slider').find('ng5-slider').find('span[aria-valuemax="250"]').invoke('attr', 'aria-valuetext', "103")
      .should('have.attr', 'aria-valuetext', '103')
    cy.scrollTo('top');
    })
  })
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can trigger a mousedown event and then a mousemove to a specific place place in the document. At least that is how I do it in my tests.

```
cy.get('span[data-cy="priceSlider"] > span.MuiSlider-thumb[data-index="0"] ')
            .focus()
            .trigger("mousedown")
            .trigger("mousemove", { which: 1, pageX: 460 })
```

Link to the docu: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/trigger.html#Mouse-Events

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using this approach:

```
cy.get('mat-slider')
  .then(($slider) => {
    const min = 0;
    const max = 100;
    const step = 1;
    const value = 0; //your value here
    const width = $slider.width();
    const range = max - min;
    const steps = range / step;
    const stepWidth = width / steps;
    const from = $slider.offset().left;
    const to = from + (stepWidth * (value / step));

    cy.get('.mat-slider-thumb') // find the slider thumb element
      .trigger('mousedown', { button: 0 }) // simulate a mouse down event
      .trigger('mousemove', { clientX: from }) // simulate a mouse move event to the start position
      .trigger('mousemove', { clientX: to }) // simulate a mouse move event to the target position
      .trigger('mouseup', { force: true }); // simulate a mouse up event to release the thumb
  });
```